# What's in a ValueList?

Tags: undocumented, internals

I discovered a command `` System`Private`ValueList `` in my `.mx` dumps. It's an internal command and thus undocumented, but from the little I could find online I understood that it used to be available in `` System` `` prior to version 3.0, albeit still undocumented, and used sometimes by package developers for input and output formatting ([1](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=784744)). In [2](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1998/Jan/msg00363.html) it is said that it is now accessible through the Private context, which is indeed what [1](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=784744) is doing in a simple version check.

Interestingly, [2](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1998/Jan/msg00363.html) says that "a certain amount of misinformation has been posted about it" but I can't seem to find what they are referring to, or I can't identify it as a misinformation. The most comprehensive review I found is [3](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1998/Jan/msg00280.html), but the examples no longer work in 10.2 even after the change in the context.

**Edit:** They work but slightly differently, thanks, Mr.Wizard! This does not affect the main question that follows.

I wouldn't need to care but [3](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1998/Jan/msg00280.html) says it can do something "you cannot achieve using the ordinary built-in commands", and this intrigues me. Does anyone know what all the talk about the similarity and difference from `HoldForm` is about, and what's the command's purpose? Internally it seems to be used rather often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that `ValueList` is quite boring after all, it's just used to hold several variables in their unevaluated form and printing them nicely on both `InputForm` and `OutputForm` (individual entries become separated by double line breaks). The `InputForm` behaviour is a difference from `HoldForm`, and so is the list-like behaviour, i.e., `ValueList[a,b,c]` can be used directly instead of nesting `HoldForm@List[a,b,c]`. Otherwise they seem to be identical.

In the link ([1](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=784744)) above this is used to pretty print `InputForm` like

```
Format[e_Times,InputForm]:=ValueList[e]/.Power->power/.Times->System`Times;
```

while for `OutputForm` a `HoldForm` is sufficient,

```
Format[e_Times]:=HoldForm[e]/.Power->power/.Times->System`Times;
```

underlining the fact the only reason not to use `HoldForm` in both is that it displays in `InputForm`, which is undesirable.

Internally it is used in dumps to store rewrite rules of a symbol like `DownValues`, separated into those which can be matched directly (like `f[1]`) and those which use patterns, presumably for the purposes of optimisation. One can indeed assign this directly, like

```
DownValues[f] := 
 System`Private`ValueList[System`Private`ValueList[], 
  System`Private`ValueList[f[u_] :> u^2, f[u_, v_] -> u + v]]
```

(interestingly, giving the full name an alias like `ValueList` results in DownValues rejecting the right hand side on the basis of not being a list), which matches closely the dump contents, albeit the separation is not too important as Mathematica seems to flatten and reorganize this anyway; even a single-level VL works.

**Edit**: In most cases simply assigning a `List` evades evaluation of the right-hand side, too, but an example in ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35773117/1537925)) shows a case where the contents of a `List` is evaluated while assigning to a downvalue. `ValueList` provides a possible solution to avoid the side effects of this evaluation.

The differentiation between `Rule`s and `RuleDelayed`'s seems to be lost on first sight,

```
DownValues[f]
```

> {HoldPattern[f[u_]] :> u^2, HoldPattern[f[u_, v_]] :> u + v}

but is retained for the purposes of `Definition`, `Save`, etc.

There might be other use cases I am not aware of but this answers all the parts of the question as posed.

Answer (score 4):

In version 10.1.0 under Windows the examples in your reference (3) still work:

```
System`Private`ValueList[Plus[1, 2^2, 3]] // InputForm
```

> 1 + 2^2 + 3

```
System`Private`ValueList[Plus[1, 2^2, 3]] // OutputForm
```

> 1 + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3

```
System`Private`ValueList[Plus[1, 2^2, 3]] // FullForm
```

> System`Private`ValueList[Plus[1, Power[2, 2], 3]]

Comment: In my system (10.2, Linux) if no `Form` wrapper is used the `FullForm` displays, which is contrary to the referenced answer. But it's my bad I didn't try them.

Comment: @TheVee Sorry, you're right, I missed the first example.